# Why does a spring work the way it does?

Tags: material-science, spring, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I am wondering if anyone can explain what exactly makes the shape of a spring so good at creating something so elastic and good at converting between kinetic and potential energy.

The metal itself isn't nearly as elastic. A spring made of copper wire can be compressed very easily, but a block of copper can be hardly compressed at all.

A major component to the explanation seems to be the fact that the shape of a spring takes advantage of the shear modulus of the metal wire. I am wondering if there can be a more rigorous explanation involving the concepts of stress and strain.

I'll state my quandary in the form of two basic questions. How does the shape of the spring make it so good at storing and releasing energy? And how does the shape make it so elastic?

Comment: The one statement you wrote about the metals i.e metals itself isn't nearly elastic is wrong. Infact metals are more elastic than rubbers and the most relevant equivalent stuff.

Comment: The metal inside a spring is much longer than the spring itself.

Comment: [And so the twist per unit uncoiled length is small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_\(mechanics\)), as is the maximum shear stress (at the surface of the narrow rod). Does this get at what you're asking about?

Comment: Elasticity is defined as the ability of a material body to resist deformation on the application of a force and the ability to return to the original configuration when that force is removed.

Comment: The theory of a spiral spring is covered on old text books eg [Champion - Properties of Matter p62](https://archive.org/details/propertiesofmatt032956mbp/page/n61/mode/2up).